# StaleConnectionException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle, websphere, oracle12c, ojdbc

We are using Oracle as the database for our application.

**Issue:**

The application runs well most of the time, but we get this "No more data to read from socket" error intermittently.

We never had this error before. Recently we had DB upgradtion from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c. And we changed the ojdbc driver jar version.

Now we face the below issue intermittently.

Can it be because of ojdbc jar version? or anything to be corrected at DB? or Websphere?

**Version:**

Oracle  : Oracle12c

ojdbc jar : ojdbc7

JDK :1.7

Server: Websphere Application Server 8.5

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:631) ~[spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104) ~[spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58) ~[spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.loadRequest(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.domain.service.implementation.myServiceImplementation.getDataFromDao(MyServiceImplementation.java:67)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2297) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at com.domain.dao.implementation.MyDaoImplementation.loadRequest(<yDaoImplementation.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) ~[na:2.6 (10-07-2015)]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: No more data to read from socket
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542) ~[na:2.6 (10-07-2015)]
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:627) ~[rsahelpers.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf081545.03]]
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:686) ~[rsahelpers.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf081545.03]]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2267) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1191) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:728) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1849) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    ... 209 common frames omitted
[7/31/17 16:33:32 ] SystemOut     16:33:32.249 [WebContainer : 2] ERROR o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - Could not toggle autocommit
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcWrapper.createClosedException(WSJdbcWrapper.java:122) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.activate(WSJdbcConnection.java:2901) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(WSJdbcConnection.java:3477) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:228) [hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:220) [hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:196) [hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:107) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:539) [spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845) [spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822) [spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410) [spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114) [spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.domain.module.implementation.MyModuleImplementation.getListOfItems(MyModuleImplementation.java:54)
[7/31/17 16:33:32 ] LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0016E: Resource jdbc/ORACLEAPPL failed to complete. Exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.rollback(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:421)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.cleanup(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.end(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.postInvoke(WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.java:334)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.postInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: DSRA0080E: An exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original exception message: No more data to read from socket.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.translateSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1584)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbSpiLocalTransactionImpl.rollback(WSRdbSpiLocalTransactionImpl.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.rollback(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:401)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: No more data to read from socket DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08000, Error Code = 17,410
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:627)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2267)
    ... 27 more
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08000, Error Code = 17,410
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:725)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3970)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.rollback(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbSpiLocalTransactionImpl.rollback(WSRdbSpiLocalTransactionImpl.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.rollback(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:401)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.cleanup(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.end(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.postInvoke(WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.java:334)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.postInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
[7/31/17 16:33:32] 0000011b WSRdbManagedC W   DSRA0180W: Exception detected during ManagedConnection.destroy().  The exception is:  com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: DSRA0080E: An exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original exception message: No more data to read from socket. with SQL State : 08000 SQL Code : 17410
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:725)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3970)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.rollback(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cleanupTransactions(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:4690)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.destroy(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:3833)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.destroy(MCWrapper.java:2087)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.returnToFreePool(FreePool.java:527)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.release(PoolManager.java:2903)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.releaseToPoolManager(MCWrapper.java:2608)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.afterCompletion(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:1295)
    at com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.driveSynchronization(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:581)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableLocalTranCoordImpl.informSynchronizations(EmbeddableLocalTranCoordImpl.java:220)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.cleanup(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1063)
    at com.ibm.tx.ltc.impl.LocalTranCoordImpl.end(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.postInvoke(WebAppTransactionCollaboratorImpl.java:334)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.postInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08000, Error Code = 17,410
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: OP, did you get your issue resolved? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, Issue got fixed after changing the oracle binaries according to Oracle12c and and I had kept ojdbc7.jar at  Websphere server level.

Comment: Thanks, so which version did you end up using? I can see from your comment in the answer below, that you upgraded from ojdbc6 to ojdbc7 and it didn't work.

Comment: The issue got fixed with ojdbc7.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the connection to the database was suddenly disconnected.  I would try updating your JDBC driver since you are using an 11g driver with a 12c database.  In general your database and driver versions should match.  There could be another root cause, such as a firewall timeout cutting the connection, but since you recently did a database upgrade I would start with upgrading the driver.

Comment: We dont have Firewall. I keep ojdbc6 jar as I have different DB version. I mean in I have Oracle 11g  in one environment whereas Oracle 12c in DEV,TEST environments. I thought ojdbc6 jar can support both DB versions.

Comment: Looking at [Oracle's documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02) again you really actually should be able to use either the 11.2 ojdbc6 or 12.1 ojdbc6 drivers with both 11g and 12c databases, although best practice to use a JDBC driver that is the same as or higher than the Oracle database version.  So to understand, this is happening in your environments using ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0 and 12c database, but not in your environment that is using the same driver with an 11g database?  Or is it happening in both environments?

Comment: It is happening in the environment where Oracle12c version is available.

Comment: I would try the latest version of the 12.1 ojdbc6 driver to see if that helps.  While there are many root causes that could result in the error you are seeing (firewall timeouts, network issues, multithreaded connection access) it seems more likely to be database related since the only difference in your environments is the database version.

Comment: As mentioned in Oracle documentation (you mentioned in your comment)9, can this be linked to JDK version? For Oracle12 c and JDK 1.7 ojdbc7.jar is suggested?

Comment: Yes, according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03 you should be using ojdbc7.jar for JDK 1.7.

Comment: I changed version of the jar from ojdbc6.jar to ojdbc7.jar. But the issue remains

Comment: @AlagammalP I hope that you resolved your problem in the meantime. In my case, I had a similar problem, I modified the fetch type in order to generate smaller queries and I got rid of this Oracle error 17410 No more data to read from socket.